# Remove duplicates from Linked List, error check

Tags: c++, linked-list, duplicates, c++14

I need to remove all duplicates from given linked list, but i'm not sure if my function is safe and will work. Currently it works for basic tests.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Node{
    Node* next{};
    int value{};
};

Node* deleteDuplicates(Node* first){
    if(first==nullptr){
        return nullptr;
    }
    std::vector<int> uniqueValues;
    uniqueValues.push_back(first->value);
    Node* curr=first->next;
    Node* prev=first;
    while(curr!=nullptr){
        if(std::find(uniqueValues.begin(),uniqueValues.end(),curr->value)!=uniqueValues.end()){
            prev->next=curr->next;
            delete curr;
            curr=prev->next;
            continue;
        }
        uniqueValues.push_back(curr->value);
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    return first;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the text of the code challenge/task? Is the input list sorted? Are you allowed to use a vector? If allowed, is there any limitation on using another data structure?

Comment: It's just: delete all duplicates from given linked list. I'm allowed to do it however i want.

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly. We could improve the time complexity by putting unique values in a `set` instead of in a `vector`. Lookup in a `set` has a better time complexity.

So then:

```
Node* deleteDuplicates(Node* first) {
    if (!first) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    std::set<int> uniqueValues;
    uniqueValues.insert(first->value);
    Node* curr = first->next;
    Node* prev = first;
    while (curr) {
        // C++20: you can use the contains method instead:
        if (uniqueValues.find(curr->value) != uniqueValues.end()) {
            prev->next = curr->next;
            delete curr;
            curr = prev->next;
            continue;
        }
        uniqueValues.insert(curr->value);
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return first;
}
```